# Can open react-bootstrap modal but closing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to let modal screen to disappear when I click close or save & close button. But I cannot find which line prevent close feature to work.

What could be wrong? I really want to let modal to disappear when I click button inside of it.

note: I use latest react-bootstrap (bootstrap 5)

```
function MemberMgt() {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    const handleCloseClick = () => {
        setShowModal(false);
    };
    const handleEditClick = () => {
        setShowModal(true);
    };
```

```
...                 
<tr onClick={handleEditClick}>
                        <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleCloseClick}>
                            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                <Modal.Title>Edit Screen</Modal.Title>
                            </Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Body>
                                <li>ID</li>
                            </Modal.Body>
                            <Modal.Footer>
                                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleCloseClick}>
                                    Close
                                </Button>
                                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleCloseClick}>
                                    Save & Close
                                </Button>
                            </Modal.Footer>
                        </Modal>
...
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, it is difficult to figure out the issue from this. Can you create a sandbox/codepen example ?

Comment: I tried running this on CSB and it's working fine. Check what's missing in your code...
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-wing-g3sg7e?file=/src/App.js:80-94

Comment: Thanks, and I found the answer! The answer was simple. Just move modal code out of <tr> tag!